# Задача по поиску количества палиндромов, которые можно представить в виде суммы квадратов последовательных чисел

Tags: java, алгоритм

Здраствуйте, я месяц уже изучаю Java и частенько решаю задачи на таком сайте как CodeWars. И вот во время решения очередного задания, произошла ошибка. P.S: если в друг вам будет не понятно то что я объяснил, перейдите по ссылке и посмотрите задание сами: [задание на поиск палиндромов](https://www.codewars.com/kata/599b1a4a3c5292b4cc0000d5), возможно попробуйте решите его и подскажите мне что я не так сделал. Ибо мой алгоритм то возвращает значение на 1 больше то меньше. Ну или предложите свою реализацию

Дело в том что тесты проходят успешно. Но во время попытки опубликовать свое решение рандомные тесты дают ошибку. Суть задания в том что-бы посчитать количество чисел палиндромов (это то что задом наперед означет тоже самое). Например: 151, 99. Как их не крути с одно и другой стороны они читаются как 99, и 151. Ну или на примере слова, например: ДОВОД. С какой стороны не прочти оно все равно ДОВОД.).

**Условие:** Так вот на вход вы получаете какоето значение например 1000 (в коде это n) и нужно вернуть количество чисел палиндромов которые получаются в результате сложения последовательных чисел в квадрате и в итоге результат сложения должен быть меньше чем 1000 (Тоесть, то n которое мы изначально знаем).

Например: 1^2 + 2^2 = 5. Или так: 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 + 10^2 + 11^2 + 12^2 = 595. От сюда мы видем что число 595 действительно палиндром. Который был создан из суммы последовательных квадратов. Однозначные тоже считаются палиндромами так как созданы из последовательности суммы квадратов.

Посмотрите мой код: (Помогите понять что не так в нем работает):

```
public static int values (int n){
    //..
  int countElement = 0;
    // Суть первого цикла в том что-бы по очереди брать значения начинающиеся с 1, а второй добавляет к этому значению последовательность. Получается что-то типа: 1^2 + 2^2...
    for(int i = 1; isTwoPowResult(i, n); i++) { 
      
      int sum = (int) Math.pow(i, 2); 
      
      for(int j = i + 1; ; j++) {
        
        sum += (int) Math.pow(j, 2);
        
        if(sum >= n) { 
          break;
        }
        
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(sum));
        
        if(new String(builder).equals(new String(builder.reverse()))) { 
           countElement++;
        }           
       } 
      }
   return countElement;
}

public static boolean isTwoPowResult(int index, int n) { 
   return ((int) Math.pow(index, 2) + ((int) Math.pow(++index, 2))) <=  n;
}
```

Comment: Укажите ограничения на n. Пока не разобрался в чем проблема, но первое что предложил бы сделать, так это заменить везде `(int) Math.pow(x, 2)` на `x*x`. Так проще читать и гарантированно не будут возникать проблемы с точностью.

Comment: первый цикл нужно до n а не до n^2 + функция возведения неправильная, она возвращает вам булевое значение

Comment: @GGO стиль конечно у автора странный, но, как я понял, там написано что цикл идет от 1 и до тех пор пока `i^2 +(i+1)^2 <= n`, что в принципе имеет смысл.

Comment: @GGO извеняюсь за странный стиль, default locale все правильно подметил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что две разные последовательности чисел могут давать одинаковую сумму квадратов чисел.

Например: сумма квадратов от 9 до 118 равна 554455, но сумма квадратов от 331 до 335 также равна 554455. Соответственно, это число в Вашем решении будет посчитано дважды.

Чтобы исправить, нужно в методе считать только уникальные значения `sum`. Для этого можно завести множество возможных сумм:

```
Set<Integer> valueSet = new HashSet<>();
```

Добавлять в него все полученные значения:

```
 valueSet.add(sum);
```

И возвращать количество найденных уникальных сумм, т.е. размер множества:

```
 return valueSet.size();
```

Без переменной `countElement` можно обойтись.

Я внес эти изменения и задача прошла на codewars.

P.S. В любом случае предложил бы возводить числа в квадрат через простое перемножение `x*x`, а не через `(int) Math.pow(x, 2)`. Функция `Math.pow` работает с вещественными числами, и соответственно, может давать результаты с погрешностью . Здесь это вроде как не влияет на результат, но в дальнейшем погрешность может подвести.